# How common is ' to trickle down' used in contexts unconnected to finance, wealth, etc.?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have been using *trickle down* in contexts totally irrelevant to economy and similar concepts. Here is an example:

> Any change involving a particular part of an ecosystem will **trickle down**, in due course, **to** the others.

Many Google results are related, in a way or the other, to national wealth, haves and have-nots, etc.

The following is a rare example Google fetches:

> That news may take at least a day to **trickle down to** the street.

I'd like to know if this usage is **unacceptable** or simply **less common**? What could be a better alternative, if this is not acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

[Trickle down](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trickle+down)  has also an idiomatic usage besides the economic one: (from TFD)

> - trickle down (to someone or something):
>
>   1. Lit. [for a liquid] **to seep or dribble downward to reach someone or something**. The water trickled down the wall to the floor. It trickled down very slowly.
>   2. Fig. [for something] **to be distributed to someone or something in little bits at a time.** The results of the improved economy trickled down to people at lower-income levels. Information about what happened finally trickled down to me.

Comment: The second example of the second sense should allow this usage then. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, in a figurative way you can use it with the meaning shown in the example.

Comment: Except that "trickle down" might not be the best metaphor for an ecosystem's interconnectedness.